# Spark Streaming: Using PairRDD.saveAsNewHadoopDataset function to save data to HBase

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, hbase, spark-streaming

I want to save a Twitter stream in a HBase database. What I have now, is the Saprk Application to receive and transform the data. But I don't know how to save my TwitterStream into HBase?

The only thing I found that could be useful is the `PairRDD.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(conf)` method. But how shall I use it, which Configurations do I have to make to able to save the RDD data to my HBase table?

The only thing I found yet is the HBase client library, which can insert data to a table via Put objects. But this isn't a solution for inside a Spark program, is it (would be necessary to iterate over all items inside the RDD!!)?

Can someone give an example in JAVA? My main problem seems to be the set-up of the `org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration` instance, I have to submit in the `saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset`...

Here a code snippet:

```
JavaReceiverInputDStream<Status> statusDStream = TwitterUtils.createStream(streamingCtx);

JavaPairDStream<Long, String> statusPairDStream = statusDStream.mapToPair(new PairFunction<Status, Long, String>() {
    public Tuple2<Long, String> call(Status status) throws Exception {
        return new Tuple2<Long, String> (status.getId(), status.getText());
    }
});

statusPairDStream.foreachRDD(new Function<JavaPairRDD<Long,String>, Void>() {
    public Void call(JavaPairRDD<Long, String> status) throws Exception {
        org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        status.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(conf);
        // HBase PUT here can't be correct!?
        return null;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[First thing is functions are discouraged, if you are using java 8. Pls. use lambda.](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/04/making-apache-spark-easier-to-use-in-java-with-java-8/)

Below code snippet could address all your queries.

sample snippet:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.RowFactory;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType;
....


  public static void processYourMessages(final JavaRDD<YourMessage> rdd, final HiveContext sqlContext, 
                    , MyMessageUtil messageutil) throws Exception {
        final JavaRDD<Row> yourrdd = rdd.filter(msg -> messageutil.filterType(.....) // create a java rdd
        final JavaPairRDD<ImmutableBytesWritable, Put> yourrddPuts = yourrdd.mapToPair(row -> messageutil.getPuts(row));
        yourrddPuts.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(conf);       
    }
```

where conf  is like below

```
private Configuration conf =   HBaseConfiguration.create();
        conf.set(ZOOKEEPER_QUORUM, "comma seperated list of zookeeper quorum");
        conf.set("hbase.mapred.outputtable", "your table name");
        conf.set("mapreduce.outputformat.class", "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableOutputFormat");
```

`MyMessageUtil` has `getPuts` methods which is like below

```
public Tuple2<ImmutableBytesWritable, Put> getPuts(Row row) throws Exception {

        Put put = ..// prepare your put with all the columns you have.
        return new Tuple2<ImmutableBytesWritable, Put>(new ImmutableBytesWritable(), put);
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your solution, looks pretty good. I will try it on Monday and give feedback. Thank you!

Comment: if incase any issues pls keep posted

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you! Another example can be found here: https://sparkkb.wordpress.com/2015/05/04/save-javardd-to-hbase-using-saveasnewapihadoopdataset-spark-api-java-coding/